# How to pack two integers into a 4 bit short in Java?

Tags: java, bit, short

I've run into a problem that requires me to pack and unpack two data values into a short. Unfortunately, the first 12 bits of the short are being used for something else, which leaves me with 4 bits to accomplish what I aim to do. However, I don't really know where to go or if this is even possible. I understand that there would be restrictions on the values I can pack into the 4 bits, but I am unsure on the exact value of those restrictions. Here are some of the facts that I know already.

Say I have two variables, x and y.

- If y = 0, then x can equal any number between 0-15.
- As y increases, the number of bits that x can occupy must decrease, similar to an inverse relationship.

  - Y must be limited to a certain value to allow room for X.
  - At Y's max, x = 0
- X's bit count + Y's bit count = 4

Any help or impossibilities about how to pack this data together with the given restrictions would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take a piece of paper and write on it, one to a line, each of the 16 bit patterns available to you.  Then make two columns, one headed `x` the other `y`, and assign the correct (for your purposes) interpretations (in terms of `x` and `y`) for each of the bit patterns.  Not sure what more you can do.

Comment: If y=0 and x can be 0-15, then you're overlapping with the reverse case of x=0 and y in 0-15, and there's no way to tell them apart.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to construct an encoder/decoder of sorts, see - http://www.edgefxkits.com/blog/encoders-and-decoders-truth-tables/ - The link may be a bit advanced looking at first, but it will show how you can "encode" many bits into just a few bits, and get back many bits from just a few bits (decoder). This is generally used in hardware circuits, but can be applied to software just the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 4 bits, the only thing you can sensibly do is use fixed size integers

Either X and Y are both 0-3, or X is 0-1 and Y is 0-7 (or vice versa)

If you try to do anything beyond this and have variable length integers, you'll have no idea which of the following 1111 means

```
x=3 y=3
x=1 y=7
x=7 y=1
x=15 y=0
x=0 y=15
```

Otherwise it's like saying "We can store one 2-digit numbers, so pick two numbers that add up to 99 or less and then add them together and store that"...It works fine, until you try to take the stored value and split it back down again. eg how do you know what the values were if you can just see "86" in the field? You've got no idea if it's 1+85, 85+1, 40+46, or any other potential combination

The correct answer in that case is to store two numbers between 0 and 9 instead, so 86 is 8 + 6... but you naturally lose an order of magnitude in the size of numbers we can store. Working in base 2 is no different.

You have 16 unique values. You can assign these to different combinations of x and y, but you will never be able to store more than 16 different combinations in 4 bits.

The only exception to this is if you have enough space to use a delimiter between your numbers... but in your case 4 bits is so short that it's more efficient to just use 2x 2-bit or 1x 3-bit and 1x 1-bit fixed-length numbers.

Comment: Ahh I see. So the issue is not packing the data together but rather unpacking the data. Alright, I will have to see if I can find another work around to getting my data stored

Comment: Precisely. You have exactly 16 unique values and there's nothing you can do about that. Either X and Y are 0-3, or one is 0-1 and the other is 0-7, those are your options (or a single number of 0-15). Naturally you could choose to store any 16 other arbitrary values, but they would be fixed values and you have exactly 16 of them available.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it really cleared up a lot of the questions I had!